# Stationary seasonal model

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality

Given Box-Jenkins seasonal model on p.310

$$\phi_p(B)\Phi_P(B^s)\triangledown^d\triangledown_s^Dz_t =\theta_q(B)\Theta_Q(B^s)a_t$$

I want to show that the $z_t$ process is stationary (or not). How should I do this. Take for example  $\phi_p(B)\Phi_P(B^s)=(1-0.2B^2)(1-6B^{12}+12B^{24})$ where seasonality=12. I had 3 possible ideas:

(1) check non-seasonal AR $\phi_p(B)$ and seasonal AR $\Phi_P(B^s)$ for stationarity independently, that is, that the roots of $(1-0.2B^2)=0$ lie outside the unit circle and same for the roots of $(1-6B^{12}+12B^{24})=0$. Both must be true for the process to be stationary

(2) same as above, except this time test roots of $(1-0.2B^2)=0$ and $(1-6B+12B^2)=0$

(3) expanding out $\phi_p(B)\Phi_P(B^s)$, so effectively you get high-degree polynomial $1 - 0.2 B^2 - 6 B^{12} + 1.2 B^{14} + 12 B^{24} - 2.4B^{26}$. Now we check this polynomial, that the roots lie outside the unit circle

Which of these is correct? and can that choice be justified/proven to work. If none, how do I do the proof?